# How to access the attributes defined in constructor into a nested function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, nested-function

```
class texting:
    def __init__(self,fname,empid):
        self.fname = fname
        self.empid = empid
    def record(self):
        print("employee name = {} and his employee id is {}".format(self.fname,self.empid))
    def strop(self):
        def str_print():
            print(self.fname)
obj_texting = texting('ABC',101)
obj_texting.record()
obj_texting.strop()
```

In above piece of code, Nested function **str_print()** is not able to print the name. I don't understand how to access **self.fname** in nested function.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your issue.  Function str_print is able to print self.fname if you call it from function strop i.e. add the line str_print() as the last line in function strop.  Currently, str_print is defined but not called.

Answer (score 0):

function str_print inside a function defined on the stack,it will be destroyed when the function is executed. you can't use this method outside of function.